# Small file transfer thru java socket, receiver instream seemed never gets it

Tags: java, sockets, networking

supposedly we use a canonical inputstream reading methods:

```
 while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    System.out.println(bytesRead);
    bos.flush();
 }
```

for both sender and recieving side do the job. I had sender showing a completed sent status but the reciever keep blocked not read in anything until sender start sending other stuff then gets filled up exit the loop. what could be missing for the puzzle here. thanks!

Comment: Have you called `Socket.shutdownOutput()` for the sender? If not, the receiver may be wait until timeout for further incoming bytes.

Comment: No. Would Socket.shutdownOutput() merely just shut down the last transmisstion operation or shut down the whole socket outstream? The latter is not a solution  since i need socket say connected.

Comment: It will shutdown the whole outstream of the socket. You cannot reuse the socket for writing after that, only for reading an answer, if you want. If you are resusing the senders socket, you should think about to change it to one connection per transmission.

Comment: Why so? why not the sentinel eof -1 sent over or file size info do the trick?

Comment: I never had to call shutdown() in my client/sever apps before, so I assume that it is not it.
You are omitting way to much information from this post for us to be able to give you and informed solution, so it is mainly about blind guessing here:
1) are you writing and reading to and from the same socket? [I have see it happen]
2) where is your code for receiver/reader?

Comment: Surely both sides use same socket. The reader code is at top section of the post....

Comment: If you want to keep the socket opened at the sender side, then, you need to send the file's size before sending the file's data, so that, you know when to stop reading.Otherwise, if you close the socket at the sender side, before getting the -1 you should get a 0, indicating the socket has been closed or shutdown'ed. If after getting the 0 you still keep read(ing) you get a -1.

Comment: Has anyone put the comments here actually tried a small file tranfer, have a go, i tried numerous conditions for the while loop, it's just not reading anything, only greater size file is ticking at reciever ;-0